# How to set cursor field name from another cursor? Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to take cursor fields names from another cursor like this:

```
FOR rec1 IN (SELECT * FROM table1) LOOP  
   FOR rec2 IN (SELECT * FROM table2) LOOP  
       IF rec1.[rec2.field_name] <> '*' THEN 
         ...                                          
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is really not designed for this kind of behavior.  The only way I can think of to achieve this is to use dynamic PL/SQL to produce the functionality you're looking for:

```
declare
  v_field_value varchar2(2000);
begin
  FOR rec1 IN (SELECT * FROM table1) LOOP  
     FOR rec2 IN (SELECT * FROM table2) LOOP  
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin :value := :rec1.' 
                           || :rec2.field_name || '; end;' 
            USING OUT v_field_value, IN rec1;
         IF v_field_value  <> '*' THEN 
           ...                                          
         END IF;
     END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

However, just because this approach can work doesn't mean you should use it.  If your field is not a string, for instance, Oracle will implicitly convert the value, which may result in a different value than what you expect. If this were my code, I would only use this as a last resort, after considering implementing the same functionality outside the database and redesigning the database's structure to avoid the need for this type of code.

---

Based on the comment the error mentioned in the comment, I've modified the code so to pass the records in using bind variables.

Comment: I receive error: "Identifier 'rec1.name' must be declared". In my opinion, the record "rec1" is not visible in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I understand what your problem is, you can access the outer cursor-loop's record just like you would expect from a variable that is declared in a scope above the current one.

```
for rec1 in (SELECT * FROM table1) loop
   for rec2 in (SELECT * FROM table2) loop
       if rec1.field = 1 and rec2.field_name <> '*' then
         ...                                          
       end if;
   end loop;
end loop;
```

kinda like

```
declare
  i Integer;
begin
  declare 
     x Integer;
  begin
     i := x;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: no, I need to access the outer cursor record field by the name which contains the inner cursor